# Visual Basic: Force App to Stop

Tags: vb.net, crash

How can I simulate; [app has stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLG0m.png)
After I click a button? I'm trying to make my program display that (exactly) after I click a button.

Comment: Why exactly would you want to pretend that your app is not working?

Comment: Fastest way: Put `Throw New Exception()` in a place that is not surrounded by a `Try/Catch`.

Comment: If you are doing it right then you'll never see this, apps that crash without any diagnostic are pretty broken.  If you have to: `Environment.FailFast("kaboom")

Answer (score 0):

easy way to do this is,

1. let your app crash in the first place ( cause some sort of exception) take a screenshot from that exact message.
2. Create a new form called mCrashForm, place a picturebox with the screenshot of that message ( leave out the close Program button.
3. Create a button in your main Form to open the crashForm with mCrashForm.Show()
4. Create a Button in mCrashForm which says "Close program" which executes this code snippet when pressed mCrashForm.Close()

Comment: @Visual Vince Darn i need 50 reputation so badly to finaly starting add comments to question. Throw New Exception() wont work for him because it wont popup his exact desired window, it will just throw an exception (for me atleast) and give the options to either ignore and keep running or to quit the application or to show details

Comment: How to throw an exception?